# Pass a table init with pointers to CUDA devicememory

Tags: c, pointers, memory, cuda, copy

Inside this short example, I'm trying to pass a table with a `struct` init with pointers in the cuda device memory. Copy to host -> device, device -> host seems works but  in the `_*global*_`function nothing works. Values for`dA` are null and I can't change them.

I don't know how to copy values from **`A`** to **`dA`**. If I use basic table like this      `fcomplex A[N][N]` it works, but here this is not what I want to do. This is the code :

```
#include<assert.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>

#define N 5// side of matrix containing data

#define checkCudaErrors(val) check( (val), #val, __FILE__, __LINE__)

typedef struct {float re,im;} fcomplex; 

__global__ void kernel(fcomplex * da)
{
    int x = threadIdx.x;
    int y = threadIdx.y;
    int i = (N*y) + x;
    //da[i].re += 2;
    printf("%f \n",da[i].re);
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
 fcomplex  *dA,**A,**B;

 A= (fcomplex **)malloc(N * sizeof(fcomplex* ));
 B=(fcomplex **)malloc(N * sizeof( fcomplex*  ));

 for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
    A[i] = (fcomplex *)malloc(N * sizeof(fcomplex ));
    B[i] = (fcomplex *)malloc(N * sizeof(fcomplex ));
 }
 for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
 {   for (int d= 0; d < N; d++)
     {
    A[i][d].re = i*d;
    A[i][d].im = i*d;
     }
 }

 checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc((void **)&dA, (size_t)(sizeof(fcomplex)*N*N)));
 checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(dA,A,N*N*sizeof(fcomplex),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

 const dim3 blockSize(N,N);
 const dim3 gridSize(1,1);

 kernel<<<gridSize,blockSize>>>(dA);

 checkCudaErrors(cudaThreadSynchronize());
 checkCudaErrors(cudaGetLastError());

 checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(B, dA, sizeof(fcomplex)*N*N, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
 for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
 {  for (int d= 0; d < N; d++)
    {
     printf("%f-%f\n",A[i][d].re,B[i][d].re);
     printf("%f-%f\n",A[i][d].im,B[i][d].im);
    }
 }
 //verify(A,B,N);

 free(A);
 free(B);
 cudaFree(dA);
 //cudaFree(dB);
}

void verify(fcomplex ** A, fcomplex ** B, int size)
{
 for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
 {  for (int d= 0; d < size; d++)
    {
     assert(A[i][d].re==B[i][d].re);
    }
 }
 printf("Correct!");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[For simplicity, I'm only talking about A but the same applies to B]

On the CPU you've allocated an array of N pointers (A), then you allocate an array of N values for each of these pointers. On the GPU you've allocated a flat array of N*N values.

This means your two data structures are different and so your `cudaMemcpy()` is copying garbage. You have two choices:

1. Mirror the indirect data structure on the GPU - this would mean you would have one `cudaMalloc()` for the pointers, then a `cudaMalloc()` for each pointer. This get's a little ugly since you need to copy the inner pointers to the GPU, and you need to call `cudaMemcpy()` for each inner pointer (i.e. row) individually.
2. Use a flat data structure on the CPU just like on the GPU.

Using a flat data structure on both CPU and GPU would be simplest for the problem you describe, if your actual problem is more complex then it's not too hard to implement a deep copy to allow pointers inside your data structure.

Alternatively you could map the memory so that the GPU can access the CPU memory directly, but that has performance implications and is probably not what you want.